# How to edit prestashop back office product listing page

Tags: prestashop

I want to change the layout of prestashop back office product page.
So can anyone tell me which file to change so that I can modify this existing layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.... Here is what I did

1. Added content.tpl in under adminxxyy/theme/theme_name/template/controller/products
   Which showed me content of my content.tpl
2. Create a new module, register the hook and send that info via hook to content.tpl.
3. Use hook name in content.tpl like {hook h='displayProductMyWay' mod='blockcustom'}.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which page you want to edit exactly, but when you go to that page in your backoffice, like:

```
http://www.example.com/admin123/index.php?tab=AdminAttributesGroups
```

The admin123 is variable to your installation, but the ?tab=AdminAttributesGroups referes to the backoffice page you are on. These pages are located in `/var/www/admin123/tabs` in this case it's `/var/www/admin123/tabs/AdminAttributesGroups.php`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  :) Actually I wanted to change product listing page which has the link like index.php?controller=AdminProducts